# frame loss in WebP test

Tags: cobalt

There is a problem of loss of frame while doing LosslessWebp test of webp site. I wonder which part is the problem.  [reproduction image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjryS.jpg)

thank u.

Comment: Describe more or share code

Comment: Please provide more information. It works well on linux-x64x11 port of Cobalt 11.119147.

Comment: i know. but I wonder which part(webp) should be modified.

Comment: According to Stack Overflow policy, all questions should contain code. Please file Cobalt issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=181120&template=699202.

Comment: This is not a cobalt issue, can I write in the issue tracker?

Comment: Go ahead. Let's follow up on the issue tracker.